# JavaScript base64string -> binary values -> [Integer] ... performance improvement

Tags: javascript, binary, base64

I am working with Parse Server and am trying to speed up queries that use a bloom filter.

Each document has a field `bf` with number value in range 0...bloomSize, for example document Id "xyz" is hashed as `bf = 6462`

The query then loads binary bloom filter values that are encoded and saved in base64 string. To make use of indexed query in Parse Server / MongoDB I need to generate an array of integers that I can compare then with the above mentioned field. So the base64 string needs to be decoded and for each 0 in binary data I have to append an integer of that 0 value position. Currently I am using following snippet:

```
//loading [UInt8] from saved base64 string
const buf = new Buffer.from(request.user.get("daBlm"), 'base64');

var blm = Array()

for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    //iterating through 8-bit chunks and convert each UInt8 into string
    //as "toString" does not respect 8-bit length we chain ".padStart(8, '0')"
    const byte = buf[i].toString(2).padStart(8, '0');
    //loop through characters and for each 0, push the position into array
    for (var l = 0; l < byte.length; l++) {
        //push int to array for each bloom 0 value - not used bit
        if (byte[l] == "0") {
            blm.push(i*8 + l);
        } 
    }
}
//at the end is the blm array user in containedIn query constraint that use indexes    
dateQuery.containedIn("bf", blm);
```

Although it is working as intended and my query uses indexes, the generation of the array is the slowest part of the query.

I found that setting array length before entering loop speed it up slightly:

//loading [UInt8] from saved base64 string
const buf = new Buffer.from(request.user.get("daBlm"), 'base64');

```
var blm = Array()
blm.lenght = buf.lenght * 8  <-- this seems to help
for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    //iterating through 8-bit chunks and convert each UInt8 into string
    //as "toString" does not respect 8-bit length we chain ".padStart(8, '0')"
    const byte = buf[i].toString(2).padStart(8, '0');
    //loop through characters and for each 0, push the position into array
    for (var l = 0; l < byte.length; l++) {
        //push int to array for each bloom 0 value - not used bit
        if (byte[l] == "0") {
            blm.push(i*8 + l);
        } 
    }
}
```

I have not noticed any difference between `const` and `var` for the array.

I also try to generate directly from base64 with switch, but this seems to be approximately 10%-30% slower than the loop above:

```
function availArr(base64Str) {
    const lenght = base64Str.length;
    if (lenght > 0) {
        var arr = Array();
        
        for (var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            //iterating through characters of base64String
            switch (base64Str.charAt(i)) {
                case "A": //000000
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "B": //000001
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "C": //000010
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "D": //000011
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3]);break;
                case "E": //000100
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "F": //000101
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+4]);break;
                case "G": //000110
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+5]);break;
                case "H": //000111
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2]);break;
                case "I": //001000
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "J": //001001
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "K": //001010
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "L": //001011
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+3]);break;
                case "M": //001100
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "N": //001101
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+4]);break;
                case "O": //001110
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+5]);break;
                case "P": //001111
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1]);break;
                case "Q": //010000
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "R": //010001
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "S": //010010
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "T": //010011
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2, i*8+3]);break;
                case "U": //010100
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "V": //010101
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2, i*8+4]);break;
                case "W": //010110
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2, i*8+5]);break;
                case "X": //010111
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+2]);break;
                case "Y": //011000
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "Z": //011001
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "a": //011010
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "b": //011011
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+3]);break;
                case "c": //011100
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "d": //011101
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+4]);break;
                case "e": //011110
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+5]);break;
                case "f": //011111
                    arr.push(...[i*8]);break;
                case "g": //100000
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "h": //100001
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "i": //100010
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "j": //100011
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3]);break;
                case "k": //100100
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "l": //100101
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+4]);break;
                case "m": //100110
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+5]);break;
                case "n": //100111
                    arr.push(...[i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "o": //101000
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "p": //101001
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "q": //101010
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "r": //101011
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+3]);break;
                case "s": //101100
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "t": //101101
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+4]);break;
                case "u": //101110
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1, i*8+5]);break;
                case "v": //101111
                    arr.push(...[i*8+1]);break;
                case "w": //110000
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "x": //110001
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "y": //110010
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "z": //110011
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2, i*8+3]);break;
                case "0": //110100
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "1": //110101
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2, i*8+4]);break;
                case "2": //110110
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2, i*8+5]);break;
                case "3": //110111
                    arr.push(...[i*8+2]);break;
                case "4": //111000
                    arr.push(...[i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "5": //111001
                    arr.push(...[i*8+3, i*8+4]);break;
                case "6": //111010
                    arr.push(...[i*8+3, i*8+5]);break;
                case "7": //111011
                    arr.push(...[i*8+3]);break;
                case "8": //111100
                    arr.push(...[i*8+4, i*8+5]);break;
                case "9": //111101
                    arr.push(...[i*8+4]);break;
                case "+": //111110
                    arr.push(...[i*8+5]);break;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    return [];
}
```

Would anyone have an idea how to speed that up?

**EDIT2+3**

I moved the function to separate code, what keeps behaving the same, but allows me to reuse it in other functions. Later as per @Jonas recommendation I tried to avoid string conversion:

```
Buffer.prototype.toIntegerArray = function() {
    const buffLenght = this.length;
    if (buffLenght > 0) {
        const arr = Array();
        arr.lenght = buffLenght * 8
        for (var i = 0; i < buffLenght; i++) {
            //iterating through 8-bit chunks
            for (var l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
                //push int to array for each bloom 0 value - not used bit
                //corrected syntax
                if (((this[i] >> l) & 1) === 0) {
                    arr.push(i*8 + l);
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    return [];
}
```

As per @Jonas comment, the corrected syntax does find the zeros. Measuring the array build part of query through console time stamp, an average of 10 query responses with 65536 bit bloom size of all 0s (and eventually randomly half full bloom, same for all):

1. `toString(2).padStart(8, '0')` => ~ 303ms (152ms)
2. `switch` => ~322ms (145ms)
3. `(((this[i] >> l) & 1) === 0)` => ~340ms
4. `(var mask = 0x80; mask > 0; mask>>=1)` => ~354ms
5. `if ((byte & 0x80) === 0) arr.push(counter);` => 314ms (158ms)

As I noticed from the measurements, there is a big difference on looping through full 0s array and randomly half full bloom. Therefore the bigger portion does the push itself I guess.

I understand the measurement is partially misleading, but the environment is given (Parse Server cloud function) and I am unfortunately not so experienced to build more sophisticated investigations there. The harder it is that it is shared server on DBaaS.

Comment: `if((buf[i] >> l) & 1 === 0)` should also check wether the lth bit is 0

Comment: As another idea, it seems that one character in [base64](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) always gets decoded as 6 bit binary. So one could generate a lookup table from character to a zero index array. The  iterate over base64, lookup and push those results to the Array.

Comment: @Jonas In case of your first comment, I would still not get rid of the two loops, right? It would save the conversion to string and padStart, if I understood you correctly? For the second idea, I have read that switch is performing better than lookup table and I tried it that way, unfortunately not performing much better. I will add that to my question.

Comment: If the code works, you can check [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: Very interesting results. You have to iterate all the bits in the string, so no matter whether you use one loop or two, the number of iterations stays the same. The idea was to save the to string conversion, as with that a string needs to be allocated at each iteration, which I think could slow things down quite a lot.

Comment: btw you misspelled `length` quite often

Comment: Ah, and my first comment does not work because of operator predescendence, add another pair of braces  `(((this[i] >> l) & 1) === 0)`

Comment: this indeed helped, but as I was afraid, the loop is something I won't be able to avoid

Comment: `blm.lenght = buf.lenght * 8` cannot be right: with the spelling mistake it would not make any difference, and if the spelling would be correct, the `push` later on would store the values from that index onwards, not from index 0, which cannot be right.

Comment: you are correct, in my edits I forgot to correct that, but in the code later I did. I apologise, as I am not native english speaker and length is one of that words that I never get right

Comment: Did you repeat the tests a few hundred times and averaged the result? Or are these measurements from one single test? If the later, they're meaningless. Also are you measuring just the code or the whole response time? As a further thought: Does the bloom filter have to be an array of zero positions?

Comment: Then it seems that this just can't be faster the way it is. Then to get it faster you need to change the algorithm, either build the bloom filter differently or encode the data in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should improve a bit when you avoid the conversion to string with `.toString(2)`. Also the repeated `i*8+l` can be avoided by using a separate counter variable:

```
for (var i = 0, counter = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    var byte = buf[i];
    for (var mask = 0x80; mask > 0; mask>>=1) {
        if ((byte & mask) === 0) {
            blm.push(counter);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

As there are only 8 iterations of the inner loop, you could also duplicate the code 8 times, allowing for less shift operations:

```
for (var i = 0, counter = 0; i < buf.length; i++, counter+=8) {
    var byte = buf[i];
    if ((byte & 0x80) === 0) blm.push(counter);
    if ((byte & 0x40) === 0) blm.push(counter+1);
    if ((byte & 0x20) === 0) blm.push(counter+2);
    if ((byte & 0x10) === 0) blm.push(counter+3);
    if ((byte & 0x08) === 0) blm.push(counter+4);
    if ((byte & 0x04) === 0) blm.push(counter+5);
    if ((byte & 0x02) === 0) blm.push(counter+6);
    if ((byte & 0x01) === 0) blm.push(counter+7);
}
```

The idea of skipping the base64 decoding was also a good attempt, even though that means there is a longer string to iterate in pure JavaScript (instead of this happening at a lower, faster level). Still, there are things to improve in your attempt: building an array and then spreading it is a waste of time. You can just pass those arguments directly to `push`. For instance:

```
case "A": //000000
    arr.push(i*8, i*8+1, i*8+2, i*8+3, i*8+4, i*8+5);break;
```

Also, this repeated `i*8` should be avoided (same solution as above).

Comment: Thank you for your input. Perhaps is my measuring somehow influenced by the client side / actual load on server, but your solution still ranks slightly lower than @Jonas. I read somewhere that splitting large loop into sub loops can actually help ("Duff's something...?) and maybe here is the additional counter holding some reference? I am beginner in programming, sorry.

Comment: This is micro optimisation, and then it depends on which JavaScript engine you run on... how its optimiser works... I added another variation. If more speed improvement is needed, consider moving to a compiled language. C or C++ or removing the base64 encoding all together (not sure which purpose it has).

Comment: As I noticed from the measurements, there is a big difference on looping through full 0s array and randomly half full bloom. Therefore the bigger portion does the push itself I guess. Unfortunately the environment is for now defined by Parse Server, perhaps later I could move to ElasticSearch where I would be able to feed the "used" portion of bloom filter instead of the "available" one that is significantly larger array.

Comment: Indeed, the more zeroes you have, the longer the array will be that needs to be produced, so there is no way out of that.